# FlashVars QueryString

Tags: actionscript-3, query-string, flashvars

I'm unclear on the proper format for passing a QueryString Value using FlashVars, this is what I'm trying

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="part=<%= Request.QueryString["part"] %>" />
```

but this causes a parse/encode error and the swf doesnt load, same if I use single quotes ie

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="part=<%= Request.QueryString['part'] %>" />
```

Any takers?

Cheers

Comment: What language do you use? I assume is C# in ASP.Net. Is this correct?

Comment: This is just html inside an <OBJECT> tag. AS3 for the flash. It all work as far as passing static values into the flash, I'm trying to make that dynamic

Comment: this `<%= Request.QueryString['part'] %>` is not HTML. This can be your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with HTML, use the variable itself:

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="part=valueOfPartGoesHere&anotherPart=anotherPartValueGoesHere" />
```

For embed tags (required for FF and other browsers):

```
<embed flashvars="part=valueOfPartGoesHere&anotherPart=anotherPartValueGoesHere" />
```

Fot this to be dynamic you have to run a PHP, ASP or other dynamic language/platform.

If you are using PHP, use:

```
<?php echo $_GET['part']; ?>
```

instead of

```
<%= Request.QueryString['part'] %>
```

For ASP:

```
<%= Request.QueryString("part") %>
```

And so on...

Comment: Thanks for response. I can do <param name="FlashVars" value="part=123" /> and it just works no problem. But what I want is the QueryString value so the url bar is eg. "http://mysite.com/main.swf?part=123 and pass that "123", another request it might be "567" etc.. dynamic... into the <param... code. Am I missing something from your suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

expanding on rcdmk's answer, the value that flashvars expects is just a standard query string with keys and values `a=b&c=d&so_on=so_forth`.

What you have shown in your code is that you're having some engine insert some value into your HTML renderer.  That's fine, but then you need to show a sample of what this substitution will produce.  If it's not producing something that looks like the query above, then it won't work.  And if it' producing something that has a quote in it, then obviously once it's being parsed it will choke on an incomplete tag (as your substitution will end the tag prematurely and throw everything into the crapper).