# Flash - Make web link change text

Tags: flash

So, I can't find this anywhere on the web. Basically, I'm trying to do this.

I have this Flash file: http://prntscr.com/5ldtb3

I'm trying to make it so, let's say I save that file as test.swf. I'm trying to make it so I can change the text with a weblink.

e.g. http://whatever.com/test.swf?text=Test will change what says "dynamic text" to "Test".

Please help me! I'm asking you guys cause It's hard to explain and whenever I search for it online I don't get a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called `FlashVars`.

Take a look at this question: [FlashVars QueryString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423826/flashvars-querystring)

And take a look at the help docs, to implement it on the Flash side on either AS3 or AS2: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html